# Trying to show cards with flatlist on react native, using a lot of [object, Object]

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

Im working on an app that shows yu-gi-oh cards, and im trying to show the information that i have on an array that has a lot of `[object, Object]`

Like, show the cards one by one, fetching by the name, but when i save those values on an array, they just appear as `[object, Object]` and i think flatlist needs just one.

Heres the code "addFavorites":

```
export const handleFavorite = async (name) =>{
const response = await AsyncStorage.getItem("favoritesCards");
let listOfCard = await JSON.parse(response) || [];
   
    if (listOfCard.includes(name.name)) {
       
        alert(`${name.name} is already in favorites`);
    }else{
        listOfCard = [...listOfCard, (name.name)];
        alert(`${name.name} added to favorites`);
    }

 await AsyncStorage.setItem(
  "favoritesCards",
  JSON.stringify(listOfCard)
 );
 
 console.log(listOfCard);
   
};
```

Here's the FlatList:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, View, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { Title } from 'react-native-paper';
import FavoriteCard from '../components/favoriteCard'
import theme from "../theme";

const FavoriteCardList = ({ card, navigation }) =>{
    const emptyFlatList = (
        <View style={styles.title}>
            <Title>Card data not found :c</Title>
        </View>
    );
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList 
                data={card.data}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString() }
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
                ListEmptyComponent={emptyFlatList}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    return(
                        <TouchableOpacity style ={styles.text} key = {item.id} onPress={() => {navigation.navigate("Card Search", { item })}}>
                            <FavoriteCard name={item.name}  
                            type={item.type} image={item.id} style ={styles.text} race = {item.race}/>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    )
                }}
            />
        </View>
    )
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        marginTop: 30,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderRadius: 10,
        borderColor: theme.colors.red,
        marginBottom: "67%"
    },
    title: {
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: 60,
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    
});

export default FavoriteCardList;
```

And here's the code for the favorite screen:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import FavoriteCardList from '../FavoriteCardL'
import getEnvVars from '../../../enviroment';
import { Title } from 'react-native-paper';

const {apiUrl} = getEnvVars()

const FavoriteCards = ({ navigation }) => {
const [card , setCard] = useState({});
   
const getCard = async () =>{
    let list = [];
    let final = [];
    const favs = await AsyncStorage.getItem("favoritesCards");
    const data = JSON.parse(favs);
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let string = data[i];
        let repla = string.replace(/ /g, "%20");
        list.push(`${apiUrl}cardinfo.php?name=${repla}`)
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        const endpoint = `${list[i]}`
        const response = await fetch(endpoint);
        const data = await response.json();
        final.push(data)
    }
    const responses = Object.keys(final).reduce(
        (arr, key) => arr.concat(final[key]),
        []
    )

    console.log(responses);
    setCard(responses);
    
}

useEffect(() => {
    getCard();
}, [])

console.log(`card: ${card}`);

return(
    <View>
        <Title style={styles.title}>Favorite Cards</Title>
        <FavoriteCardList card={card} navigation={navigation}/>
    </View>
)
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   title: {
        marginTop: '5%',
        marginLeft: '5%'
    }
});

export default FavoriteCards;
```

What can i do to make those `[object, Object], [object, Object], etc...`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tV0px.png)

just one array with  one Object?

Comment: `[object object]` is the  default string representation of an object in js. So, card is an array of object. you can do `console.log(JSON.stringify(card, null, 2))` for printing it nice.